# Relationship of variable in log equation

Tags: logarithms

If $R_{ref}=R_{in}$ when $V_{out}=-log(\frac{V_{in}}{V_{ref}})$

What would be the relationship between $R_{ref}$ and $R_{in}$ when $V_{out}=-3log(\frac{V_{in}}{3V_{ref}})$

Comment: What are $R_{ref}$ and $R_{in}$ over here?

Comment: $R_{in}=\frac{V_{in}}{I_1}$ and $R_{ref}=\frac{V_{ref}}{I_2}$, ($I_1=I_2$)

Comment: If this is electricity then $V_{out}=-\log\left(\dfrac{V_{in}}{V_{ref}}\right)$ has the wrong dimension to be a potential difference